# ZF2 ACL -> allow for all actions in controller

Tags: permissions, zend-framework2, acl

I would like to add ACL to my ZF2 application, but I've a problem with adding permissions for all actions in the controller.

I can do this:

```
$acl->allow('roleName','zfModule', 'controllerName:actionName');
```

but not so

```
$acl->allow('roleName','zfModule', 'controllerName:all');
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to allow access to ALL resources:

```
$acl->allow('role_name', NULL);
```

Allow all privileges on your particular resouce:

```
$acl->allow('role_name', 'zfModule', NULL);
```

You could then use your action names as privileges when you build the ACL.

```
// allow a user to read and create on this controller
$acl->allow('role_name', 'zfModule/MyController', array('read', 'create', 'delete'));
```

You can treat your controller as the resrouce and each action as a privilege.

You can alternatively treat each controller/action or route as a resource, it's down to you.

Comment: Thanks, but I want permissions for all actions in controllerName.

Comment: @chudi Then define the controller as a resource, `$acl->allow('role_name', 'ModuleName/ControllerName');`

Comment: when you make the ACL you are free to decide what you considar a resource or a prigilege, you can make them anything you want to get the effect you're after.

Comment: you can make the controller the resource, and each action a privilege, or each controller/action pair a recource, it's upto you